# Angular: How to use variable in HTML getElementById

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am using ng-repeat to create multiple divs with modals, which I open by getElementById. When I hardcode the id (e.g. 'modalId'), it works but not if I try to use a variable. How do I make it work?

```
<div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4" ng-repeat="p in proj">
        <img class="myImg" ng-src="{{p.image}}" onclick="document.getElementById('{{p.id}}').style.display='block';">
        <div id="{{p.id}}" class="w3-modal" onclick="this.style.display='none';">
          <div class="w3-modal-content w3-animate-zoom">
            <img ng-src="{{p.image}}">
          </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

The p.id I want to use (line 2) is an int.

Comment: When you 'view source'/inspect was does it look like computed?

Comment: Yes the interpolation error mentioned by the other replies is displayed. But when I use ng-click, the following error is shown: Error: v0 is undefined. I m not sure what v0 is?

Comment: These are the first two error lines:
Error: v0 is undefined
anonymous/fn@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js line 231 > Function:2:738

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs: Interpolations for HTML DOM event attributes are disallowed.  Please use the ng- versions (such as ng-click instead of onclick) instead.

See here: https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$compile/nodomevents.

**Example:**

```
$scope.imgClicked = function(id){
    document.getElementById(id).style.display='block';
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<img class="myImg" ng-src="{{p.image}}" ng-click="imgClicked(p.id)">
```

Comment: Yes the interpolation error mentioned is displayed. But when I use ng-click, the following error is shown: Error: v0 is undefined. I m not sure what v0 is?

Comment: These are the first two error lines: Error: v0 is undefined anonymous/fn@ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/a‌​ngular.min.js line 231 > Function:2:738

Comment: I've added an example.

Comment: This example worked. Quite a simple solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

check this

https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$compile/nodomevents

you must be getting the below warning in your console.

Interpolations for HTML DOM event attributes are disallowed.

This error occurs when one tries to create a binding for event handler attributes like onclick, onload, onsubmit, etc.

There is no practical value in binding to these attributes and doing so only exposes your application to security vulnerabilities like XSS. For these reasons binding to event handler attributes (all attributes that start with on and formaction attribute) is not supported.

Comment: Yes the interpolation error mentioned is displayed. But when I use ng-click, the following error is shown: Error: v0 is undefined. I m not sure what v0 is?

Comment: These are the first two error lines: Error: v0 is undefined anonymous/fn@ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/a‌​ngular.min.js line 231 > Function:2:738

Comment: could you create a fiddle/plunker of your code, v0 undefined should not be due to the code shared

Comment: The example above solved it. I will take that one but thanks for your help.